# React Native: Unhandled promise rejection, invalid arguments provided

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue where I call a method and pass it parameters, then I receive an error and the action behind my button automatically runs.

Here is my render:

```
render() {
    return (<View style={styles.container}>
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Button
          accessibilityLabel='Click this button to find somewhere you and your friend can meet'
          onPress={this.handleGetDirections(this.state.lat1, this.state.lng1, this.state.lat2, this.state.lng2)}
          >
            Get Directions
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    </View>);
  }
```

Here is a bit of my error message:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: Invalid arguments provided
```

Am I not supposed to pass state into functions as parameters?

Comment: what does `handleGetDirections` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html), `onPress` is expecting a handler

It should be:

```
onPress={()=>this.handleGetDirections(this.state.lat1, this.state.lng1, this.state.lat2, this.state.lng2)}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. This works great. Really appreciate your help.